# Display dynamic content on click on menu item using semantic-ui-react

Tags: semantic-ui, sidebar, semantic-ui-react

I want to display dynamic content in Sidebar.Pusher based on the item clicked from the menu. Here is my code -

```
<Sidebar.Pushable  >
      <Sidebar as={Menu} animation='push' width='thin' visible={visible} icon='labeled' vertical inverted>
        <Menu.Item name='home' >
          <Icon name='tasks' />
          Manage categories
        </Menu.Item>
        <Menu.Item name='home' >
          <Icon name='tasks' />
          Manage products
        </Menu.Item>
      </Sidebar>
      <Sidebar.Pusher >
        <Segment basic>
          Display Dynamic content
        </Segment>
      </Sidebar.Pusher>
```

Any leads will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand the question correctly, there are a few possible solutions. In one of my projects I'm using it with React Router, so in the `<Sidebar />` component I have `<Menu.Item as={Link} to='/path' />` and then the `<Route path='/path' />` is in a  `<Switch />` statement in `<Sidebar.Pusher />`.

If you want to change rendered components without React Router, here is an example of how I implemented it.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { Sidebar, Segment, Menu } from 'semantic-ui-react'    

export default class SideNav extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props)

        this.state = {
            renderTab: 'home'
        }
    }

    changeTab(tabName) {
        this.setState({ renderTab: tabName })
    }

    render() {
        const { renderTab } = this.state
        return (
            <Sidebar.Pushable as={Segment}> 
                <Sidebar as={Menu} visible vertical>
                    <Menu.Item onClick={() => this.changeTab('home')} as='a' name='home'>
                        Home
                    </Menu.Item>
                    <Menu.Item onClick={() => this.changeTab('about')} as='a' name='about'>
                        About
                    </Menu.Item>
                </Sidebar>
                <Sidebar.Pusher> 
                    <RenderedContent tabName={renderTab} />
                </Sidebar.Pusher> 
            </Sidebar.Pushable> 
        )
    }
}

const RenderedContent = ({ tabName }) => {
    if (tabName === 'home') {
        return <Home />
    }
    if (tabName === 'about') {
        return <About />
    }
}

const Home = () => (
    <div>This is the home page</div>
)

const About = () => (
    <div>This is the about page</div>
)
```